# React Dexie.js: filter the fields during a get to avoid react component redraw

Tags: reactjs, dexie

In Dexie.js, if I do:

```
friends = useLiveQuery(async () =>
  await db.friends.toArray()
)
```

if the name of a friend changes, my component will always redraw. But I might only need to access one field, say `id`, and redrawing because `name` changed is stupid.

Is it possible to specify "keep only the field `id`", so that redraw occurs only when an id is added or removed?

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer:

The parent component could use `.primaryKeys()` instead of `.toArray()` and you get back an array of ids instead. That way, your parent component won't rerender on modify or update operations (such as `db.friends.update(x, {...})`) but if using put, add or delete, it will rerender.

```js
const friendIds = useLiveQuery(
  () => db.friends.toCollection().primaryKeys()
);
```

Original answer:

On dexie@4, it's possible to opt-in to an immutable cache mode. By doing that, the same reference will be returned for all unchanged entries from your query. Still a rerender must happen for the top component since the array will be different instance, but if every friend has it's corresponding memo() component, no rerenders will have to be done on any one except the changed one.

To use dexie@4, do `install dexie@next`.

To opt in for immutable cache, use the cache option in [Dexie constructor](https://dexie.org/docs/Dexie/Dexie)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think it solves my problem, I already have this exact same behavior since I pass only the id `friends[i].id` to the sub-components (and not the whole `friends[i]` object), and I then inside the sub-component I do `db.friend.get(id)`. So I actually want to avoid the redraw of the parent component. This seem pointless if you have a single parent component, but if this parent component is itself inside many other components (nested friends), then the performance quickly degrades.

Comment: I am also interested by this filtering for a different scenario. Let’s say I have a bunch of friends, and I’d like to have a dropdown menu with the list of the name of all friends in the list, where this dropdown menu is used in many different places (say, for instance, that you want to allow the user to create relations between friends with an helper menu). If this drowdown menu does the above query, and then does something like `friends.map (f => f.name)` to get only the list of names, this will still re-render all the dropdowns if I change, e.g., the age of any friend.

Comment: I've updated the answer - to use .primaryKeys() instead of .toArray(). This solution is for dexie@3 or 4.

Comment: Thanks, but I’m confused, I tried `db.friends.primaryKeys()` and I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).friends.primaryKeys is not a function`, while the doc says that it should be present… Also, do you have a solution when you want to get another key, or a set of key (e.g. the id and the name). I found a trick using rxjs that I need to test, but I’m curious to know if there is a better solution. (I’m running 3.2.4)

Comment: Ok, so apparently I need to add a filter or an order function like `db.friends.orderBy('id').primaryKeys()` so make it work. Yet, this still triggers a new render, I guess that this produces a new reference object.

Comment: Sorry! primaryKeys() are on Collection, to get a more performant collection, avoid using .filter() and use .toCollection() instead! Otherwise it will downgrade to cursor-based queries which are slower.

Comment: It wouldn't matter whether a reference object is produced or not. orderBy('id') or .toCollection() should make sure that it do not get affected by property changes - only creates and deletes. Using .filter() might disabled this optimisation since it has to go via IDBCursor. If still rerender happen with .toCollection().primaryKeys() this is a bug.

Comment: Even without using immutable? I tried with both versions of Dixies 3 and 4, they both reload the component. I'll fill a bug report later today.

Comment: I created a bug here https://github.com/dexie/Dexie.js/issues/1821